# How to skip database queries when calling `search` on laravel model with meili and laravel scout

Tags: laravel, laravel-scout, meilisearch

I have a `transaction` model, and other related models. While indexing in meili I eager load relations in `transaction` model and add a new key and relation, so in meili it shows a key and JSON data.

I thought calling `::search` on model will fetch data from meili and return, but `scout` seems to fetch just model id and calling database with `IN` operator to fetch models.

For complex models I don't want to hit database and just fetch whole object from meili. How is this possible? I couldn't find it in scout documentation.

Comment: _Finally, add the Laravel\Scout\Searchable trait to the model you would like to make searchable. This trait will register a model observer that will automatically keep the model in sync with your search driver_ Is this done?

Comment: Ofcourse that trait is there and I'm getting data as well. But my point is that database is hitting, that I want to skip. I want to return whole meili object without Laravel going to database for that model and fetching data from there.

Comment: Have you looked into [meilisearch-php](https://github.com/meilisearch/meilisearch-php)? The [search method](https://github.com/meilisearch/meilisearch-php/wiki/Search) might be what you are looking for...

Comment: yes I'm using `search` method only. But still I see queries in `clockwork` (using `IN` keyword).